# How do I convert a string into a byte array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a piece of text and I want to turn it into a byte array like this one:

```
        byte[,] input = new byte[4, 4] {
                                        { 0xd4, 0xe0, 0xb8, 0x1e },
                                        { 0xbf, 0xb4, 0x41, 0x27 },
                                        { 0x5d, 0x52, 0x11, 0x98 },
                                        { 0x30, 0xae, 0xf1, 0xe5 } 
                                       };
```

I'm giving the example because I have a method that can only take arguments as byte array (input is a valid argument) and I want to make sure I'm asking the right question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You get bytes based on the encoding.

e.g.

```
Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(string)
```

Comment: I tried that, I get an The best overloaded method match for 'xxx.Program.function(byte[*,*])' has some invalid arguments error

Comment: also cannot convert byte [] to byte[,]

Comment: If this solution doesn't suffice, you need to specify how the two dimensional array correlates to the string better.

Comment: You can't magically create a 2 dimensional array.  GetBytes returns a one-dimensional byte array.  There is no magical method to return an array of arrays, you will have to then take those bytes and construct the specific layout you need.

Comment: As has been mentioned, a string will convert to a one dimensional array so for a better solution you will need to explain what is represented by the two-dimensional array.